# If gravity can only change light wavelength why does then the event horizon not emit light atleast with redshift?

Tags: photons, event-horizon, aether

If gravity can only change light wavelength and not velocity why does then the event horizon not emit light at all? If the light does not move away from the EH could we talk about presence of dynamic aether nevertheless of the Michelson-Morley experiment results?

Comment: The event horizon is something infinitely far away in the future of the exterior observer. It takes an infinite amount of time for light to travel from right at the horizon to any exterior observer. What does Aether have to do here?

Answer (score 0):

The redshift of light at the event horizon asymptotically approaches infinity. This is another way of grasping the fact that the escape velocity at the event horizon is the speed of light, which is why once you get close to the EH, light cannot propagate away from it.

Another way to look at this is to realize that at the EH, time dilatation also goes asymptotically to infinity, which means that time at the EH comes to a halt or nearly so- and light then gets "frozen".

All of this is true when observing the EH from a safe distance. None of it is true from the standpoint of someone or something who is instead freely falling towards the EH.